# How to die upon access to a uninitialized Moose object attribute?

Tags: perl, moose

I have a Moose object with a non-required attribute:

```
has 'optional_attr' => (
    is       => 'ro',
    isa      => 'MyCoolType',
    required => 0,
);
```

How can I `confess` if I ever try to read this attribute while it's not set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
lazy    => 1,
default => sub { confess "not set" },
```

You might want to throw in a predicate, too:

```
predicate => 'has_optional_attr',
```

so you can find out if it's set without dying.

There's also [MooseX::LazyRequire](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX%3a%3aLazyRequire), which lets you say just:

```
use MooseX::LazyRequire;

has 'optional_attr' => (
    is            => 'ro',
    isa           => 'MyCoolType',
    lazy_required => 1,
);
```

Under the hood, it uses the same trick I suggested, but it looks more elegant in your class.

Comment: @David B, because otherwise the default value would be applied at object construction time.  `lazy` defers calculating the default value until someone asks for it, which is when you wanted to throw an exception.

Comment: Nice and simple as always. Thank you cjm.

Answer (score 2):

Would [MooseX::LazyRequire](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MooseX-LazyRequire/) fit your requirement?

Comment: Yes, because under the hood it does exactly what I suggested.  I just forgot about it.